# CupertinoTabBar page reload on tab selection

Tags: flutter, dart, bottomnavigationview

I use `CupertinoTabBar` how can I make it so that when another tab is selected, the tab page reloads and does not save its state

```
CupertinoTabScaffold(
        controller: controller,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
        tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
          iconSize: 30,
          currentIndex: currentIndex,
          onTap: (index) => setState(() => currentIndex = index),
          items: const [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home, size: 25)),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.store, size: 25,)),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_bag, size: 25)),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.person, size: 25)),
          ],
        ),
        tabBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          switch (index) {
            case 0:
              return CupertinoTabView(
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return CupertinoPageScaffold(
                    resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
                    child: HomePage(),
                  );
                },
              );
            case 1:
              return CupertinoTabView(
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return CupertinoPageScaffold(
                    resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
                    child: CatalogPage(),
                  );
                },
              );
            case 2:
              return CupertinoTabView(
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return CupertinoPageScaffold(
                    resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
                    child: ShoppingBag(),
                  );
                },
              );
            case 3:
              return CupertinoTabView(
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return CupertinoPageScaffold(
                    resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
                    child: UserProfileScaffold(),
                  );
                },
              );
            default:
              return CupertinoTabView(
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return CupertinoPageScaffold(
                    resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
                    child: HomePage(),
                  );
                },
              );
          }
        });
```